# Mid-Missouri Cosplay Convention

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

A group of people that I know are working on setting up a cosplay convention in Mid-Missouri on  June 27-30, 2013 and I wanted to let everyone here that might be interested know about it.

Should we promote the site there while we're at it?

[Cosplacon Website](http://cosplacon.squarespace.com/)

Comment: Are you planning to hand out SE flyers or dress up as [Bubbles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/) or something?

Comment: @gilles I could.  I was thinking of going as Harry Dresden

Comment: Isn't this off-topic, as it doesn't pertain to the SFF.SE site?

Comment: @keen i asked and was told by rebecca chernoff to post it on here, so *shrugs*

Comment: Interesting to have a cosplay convention in the "Show Me" state.

Comment: I live in Missouri!

Comment: @Keen I'd say that since the reason of the question is about site promotion... it seems to be on topic to me.